# How to optimally crop images with different aspect ratios

Tags: facebook, image, actionscript-3, crop

I am creating a swf player that should play audio and show a cropped images from our website (consider all images different in size and aspect ratio since users can upload whatever they want).
How should I crop these images to keep most interesting parts for example not cut of heads of people or keep the car in image with the road ?

This is what I have done by now:
I am doing this in AS3 and the coding is not the problem. I basicly load images into UILoader and then resize them keeping the aspect ratio and then hiding parts of the image that don't fit. I am even using FaceDetection in order to crop images with people but since this is not perfect I use fall-backs like center (for landscape) and top (for portrait) crop. Doing this works for some images but many of them look bad al-thou the thumbnail for image shown by Facebook is always good. 
What type of crop are they using?

NOTE:I don't want to add black or any other padding behind the image but center the image on most interesting part to fill the screen.

Comment: Facebook thumbnail always look good because that's up to people to crop the image, when I upload photos into my profile I choose what part of the photo will be available on my cover and profile pic. For example if you check the albums thumbnails you'll notice that they create a thumbnail centered base, leaving many "heads" outside of the pic

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think I misused word thumbnails or just wasn't specific enough. I was thinking about images that facebook draws from other sites that are shown in the timeline, for example if you add og:image meta tag Facebook is showing thumbnails for those images always nicely cropped al-thou those images are coming from other server and are not controlled by Facebook. Note that also having og:video on the page will generate a player in Timeline with play button and thumbnail generated from tag og:image.

Comment: You do know that those images must obey some rules? That's why they look good: **Try to keep your images as close to 1.91:1 aspect ratio as possible to display the full image in News Feed without any cropping.** in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content/

Comment: Thank you for the input, but I think you misunderstood the question. Actually they don't obey any rules since it's the same images that Facebook shows for a preview of the video player that we are trying to show when the player is loaded. In the end I did manage to get very similar results by first doing FaceDetection and then as backup doing entropy detection and deciding based on most interesting points in the picture should I do Top or Center crop.

Comment: But I am doubtful they would do it like this since JavaScript would be too slow for things like these and doing the calculations on the servers would require considerate CPU time (it's in order of 100-200ms in my code which could be reduced but I doubt it can be done in under 10ms or something). They also sometimes do BOTTOM crop which I couldn't get good results with.